# Appending to DOM after the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to append to the DOM just once after these nested loops.
**Also**, the variable `letters` is dynamic, so I would need to 'reset' my appended grid when a new string is passed to `letters`

```
let letters = "abcdefghijkl"

for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  var musicRowID = `${letters.charAt(i)}01`;
  $("#music-grid").append(`<div id="music-row-${musicRowID}" class="row no-gutters"></div>`);

  for (let j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
    var columnID = letters.charAt(i) + (j < 10 ? "0" : "") + j;
    $(`#music-row-${musicRowID}`).append(
      `<div class="col-1"><button id="${columnID}" class="btn bar song">${columnID.toUpperCase()}</button></div>`
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

After the answer from T.J. Crowder I tried to incorporate my code to be able to populate my grid from the inputs, but when I unselect one of the inputs, that row isn't cleared.

```
let letters = 'abcdefghijkl';
let html = "";

$(".list-checkbox-item").change(function() {
  let chosenLetters = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    arrayOfChoices.push(chosenLetters);
  } else {
    arrayOfChoices.splice($.inArray(chosenLetters, arrayOfChoices), 1);
  }
  letters = arrayOfChoices.sort().join(""); // Gives me a string with chosen letters ordered alphabetically
  console.log(
    `This is my string in var 'letters' ordered alphabetically (Need to clear grid after each instantiation or append after the loop): %c${letters}`,
    "color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px"
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    var musicRowID = `${letters.charAt(i)}01`;
    html += `<div id="music-row-${musicRowID}" class="row no-gutters">`; // *** No `</div>` yet

    for (let j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
      var columnID = letters.charAt(i) + (j < 10 ? "0" : "") + j;
      html += `<div class="col-1"><button id="${columnID}" class="btn bar song">${columnID.toUpperCase()}</button></div>`;
    }

    html += "</div>";
  }
  $("#music-grid").html(html);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `#music-grid` empty when all this starts (the first time)?

Comment: Just store the HTML string in a variable and keep concatenating and after the loop append that string to dom.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `#music-grid` is empty before you run this code the first time, build up the HTML in a string and then use [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace the contents of `#music-grid` rather than appending to it:

```
let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  var musicRowID = `${letters.charAt(i)}01`;
  html += `<div id="music-row-${musicRowID}" class="row no-gutters">`; // *** No `</div>` yet

  for (let j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
    var columnID = letters.charAt(i) + (j < 10 ? "0" : "") + j;
    html +=
      `<div class="col-1"><button id="${columnID}" class="btn bar song">${columnID.toUpperCase()}</button></div>`;
  }

  html += "</div>";
}
$("#music-grid").html(html);
```

You also see people building up the HTML in an array and using `array.join("")` at the end to get a single string, but with modern JavaScript engines it's really a wash either way...

Comment: Thank you, that's great! Now the only thing is how to empty the grid and rebuild it when a new `letters` string is created (there are duplicated rows currently when I get a new string in `letters`). Can I share my code somewhere here? It's a bit too large for this comment. Thanks!! (I mean the code of this function only)

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta - [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) does that (the last line above). It empties the element you call it on, then adds the HTML you provide.

Comment: mmmm then I'm misplacing something... I'm getting the values of `letters` from some input tags. I'll edit my question to be able to paste my code. :)

Comment: I edited my question. So in a way what I'm trying to achieve is a sort of 'filter". Hope I'm clear! :) And thank you!

Comment: Any tip on where I am failing in my edited question? I'd appreciate it so much! :)

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta - I think it would help if you could do a Stack Snippets demonstrating the problem -- [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). :-)

Comment: I might have sorted it! I had moved the variable `html` to the global scope, now in the function scope it seems to be working great!! I'll keep playing with it and will create a snippet if I get stuck again. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta - Great! Yes, it does want to be local. :-)